# Grab Data, Sort Data, then Load into Table View (Swift 3 : Firebase)

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an application using Firebase. What I'm trying to accomplish is getting data from Firebase, sorting that data, and then finally loading that data into a tableView once that is done.

I'm not gonna share my whole code, but here's essentially how I want it to work:

```
 var posts = [PostStruct]()
 var following = [String]()
```

...

```
 let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
 for follower in following {
     databaseRef.child("Posts").child(follower).observe(.value, with: {
         DataSnapshot in
             //Parse All The Data...

             self.posts.insert(...)

      }
 }
 self.posts.sort{$0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedDescending}

 print("Test")

 self.tableView.reloadData()
```

That `print("Test")` gets called, but it gets called before the FIRDatabase is requested, so that tells me that there is absolutely no data in the tableView when it's sorting. So, I need to find a way to only sort once the Database is finished requesting.

I can put the sort and reload method in the for statement, and that works, but it loads everything up choppy, and it's not very efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way to handle this, but you could add a counter that is incremented and then execute your sort and reload code once that counter is equal to the count of the following array.

```
var counter = 0

let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
for follower in following {
    databaseRef.child("Posts").child(follower).observe(.value, with: {
        DataSnapshot in
         //Parse All The Data...

        counter += 1

        self.posts.insert(...)

        if counter == following.count {
            self.sortPosts()
        }
    }
}

func sortPosts() {
    self.posts.sort{$0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedDescending}

    print("Test")

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually had that idea in mind, but just wasn't thinking it through properly. Thanks for the help! You're a life saver. :)

Comment: Most welcome. I've had those moments as well. Glad to help. I also like @Pentarex suggestion as well about the callback function. I think long term that solution would look a little more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

if this is for your youtube tutorials I will try to answer

I think the solution of Donny is going to work, you can do it also with a callback function

```
func getData(handle:@escaping ((Bool) -> Void)){
  let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
  for follower in following {
    databaseRef.child("Posts").child(follower).observe(.value, with: {
      DataSnapshot in
     //Parse All The Data...

      counter += 1

      self.posts.insert(...)

      if counter == following.count {
        handle(true)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then in your method where you are calling getData.

```
getData(){ ready in 
  self.posts.sort{$0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedDescending}

  print("Test")

  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Haha, thanks for noticing me. This is actually for both a personal project and a YouTube. :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of the callback function, I'll keep that in mind. Donny did solve it for me though. :)